# Largest nuclear norm of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices whose entries are between -1 and 1

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, na.numerical-analysis, random-matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $\cal M$ be the set of real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices whose entries are all in the interval $[-1, 1]$. I'm interested in understanding the largest possible nuclear norm of these matrices as a function of $n$. By nuclear norm, I mean the sum of the singular values (equivalently, the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues). Specifically,

1. What is the largest nuclear norm of these matrices as a function of $n$?
2. Which matrices $M \in \cal M$ exhibit this?

Essentially, I'm trying to find a tight upper bound on the nuclear norm of this family of matrices in terms of $n$.

Edit: I should note that I'm aware the largest eigenvalue is $n$ (take the matrix where all the entries are $1$). I would like to know (at the least) if the nuclear norm is also $O(n)$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Certainly not $O(n)$: for Hadamard matrices all eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt{n}$

Comment: ... and since the sum of squares of absolute values equals to the sum of squares of all matrix elements, i. e. is at most $n^2$, by AM-QM inequality the nuclear norm is at most $n^{3/2}$. Equality holds if and only if Hadamard matrix of order $n$ exists, which is an intriguing open question.

Comment: When there is no Hadamard matrix of size $n$, the largest nuclear norm is still of order $n^{3/2}$ (at least $n^{3/2}/\sqrt{2}$ by the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/q/13356). I would guess that it is difficult to find the exact maximum and characterize the maximizers in that case.

Comment: Have you considered restricting to PSD matrices?  You would have a linear program for each $n$.